# AttributeError: module 'IPython.core' has no attribute 'shadowns'

Tags: python, ipython, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab, dill

I'm running these lines

```
import dill
dill.load_session("session2.pkl")
```

and getting the error  `AttributeError: module 'IPython.core' has no attribute 'shadowns'`.
I've saved this session on Google Colab Notebooks. How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: I have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62041681/13626727 Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used the simple workaround:

```py
import IPython
IPython.core.shadowns = 1
```

For some extra packages missing like `google` or `google.colab`, I used

```
%%bash
mkdir google/colab
touch google/colab/__init__.py
```